# Number of columns ok in Chrome but not in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, grid

[Removed link]

There should be 5 columns. Each post has a 20% width, it looks ok in Chrome but in IE and Firefox the last column gets pushed below so there are only 4. Does anybody know why?

```
.post {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

<article class="col post">
    stuff inside
</article>
<article class="col post">
    stuff inside
</article>
<article class="col post">
    stuff inside
</article>
....
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a grid system like http://cssgrid.net/ or http://960.gs/

Comment: @Connor I'm already using http://gridpak.com/ http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/19/gridpak-the-responsive-grid-generator/#more-124759 960 is based on 12 or 24 columns and neither of them are multiple of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/166 I changed 20% to 19,8%

> Looks like Firefox calculates percentage widths a bit different than
>   WebKit. An easy fix is to allow a wee bit of wiggle room in your CSS
>   layout so that the columns don't add up to 100%.

Comment: Interesting: Firefox used to suffer from this in version 1; obviously still does

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different default settings for page margins and paddings, and I suspect that these settings are creating your problem. You should be able to eliminate your problem by using the [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) stylesheet.

Comment: Take a look at the actual site... I can't see the problem, I can't find that stylesheet anywhere, and it changes to a 3-column layout if you make the window smaller. No idea what to make of this... probably OT.

Comment: @Klaus I'm already using html5boilerplate and normalize.css comes with it.

Comment: @GGG the css is here and it's supposed to change to 3 columns because it's a responsive layout.

Comment: @Barbara the CSS is where? Can you give a link to the actual CSS file? I couldn't find it, but gave up when I realized there were several frames to look in.

Comment: @GGG http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13823768/masonry/css/style.css StOv ate my link ;) The code you need to look at is where it says Primary Styles.